# How to validate not Doctrine Entity Object

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony4, symfony-validator

I have some **$customObject** which is an instance of **CustomClass** and I want to validate it with Symfony Validation.
**CustomClass** is not a Doctrine Entity Class.

Here is my CustomClass:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
class SomeClass {
    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Status should not be empty")
    * @Assert\Choices({"200", "201"})
    */
    protected $status;

    /**
    * @Assert\Type("string")
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Content should not be empty")
    */
    protected $content;
}
```

Trying to validate it:

```
$constraints = Validation::createValidator()->validate($customObject);
```

But constraints count is always 0 even if object is invalid, seems like annotation parser ignores this object annotations. Working well on Doctrine entities in the same project.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the Validator service :

without autowiring

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
```

with autowiring

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
...
public function myMethod(ValidatorInterface $validator)
```

And then

```
$errors = $validator->validate($customObject);
```

Do you have in your config :

```
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

See more info here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Didn't know that validation with object annotations will not work if Validation is created directly (without autowiring or not as a service).

Comment: If you create the validator instance yourself, you need to make sure to enable the annotation loading which is disabled by default: `Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator()` But you should indeed rather use the service than configuring the validator every time you want to use it (and thus having to change many places when your validator config changes).